# When uploading two images, console.log(parsedRes) only returns one object instead of (the expected) two

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

So, I'm trying to fetch base64 data (urls) from two images I uploaded to the cloud/server, but when I parsed the response, I only get 1 object instead of 2 (i.e. only the url for the first image).

I must be overseeing something fundamentally, but I can't see it. Appreciate the advice.

Can some help explain to me why the code below doesn't work?

[EDIT: I've included the server code. Hopefully this makes it clearer as to the problem I'm facing]

```
    .then(token => {
        authToken = token;
        return fetch("myappURL/storeImage", 
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                image: image.base64,
                coverImage: coverImage.base64
            }),
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again1")
        dispatch(uiStopLoading());
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw(new Error());
         }
    })
    .then(parsedRes => {console.log(parsedRes)}); // I only get 1 result instead of 2 (why?!)
```

Server-side code:

```
exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
return cors(request, response, () => {....
.then(decodedToken => {
      const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
      fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg", body.image, "base64", err => {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).json({ error: err });
      });
      const bucket = gcs.bucket("myapp.appspot.com");
      const uuid = UUID();

      return bucket.upload(
        "/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg",
        {
          uploadType: "media",
          destination: "/places/" + uuid + ".jpg",
          metadata: {
              metadata: {
                  contentType: "image/jpeg",
                  firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
              }
          }
        },
        (err, file) => {
          if (!err) {
            return response.status(201).json({  // I get this returned
              imageUrl:
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
                bucket.name +
                "/o/" +
                encodeURIComponent(file.name) +
                "?alt=media&token=" +
                uuid,
              imagePath: "/places/" + uuid + ".jpg"
            });
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            return response.status(500).json({ error: err });
          }
        }
      );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Token is invalid!");
    response.status(403).json({error: "Unauthorized"});
  })
.then(decodedToken => {
      const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
      fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-coverImage.jpg", body.coverImage, "base64", err => {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).json({ error: err });
      });
      const bucket = gcs.bucket("myapp.appspot.com");
      const uuid = UUID();

      return bucket.upload(
        "/tmp/uploaded-coverImage.jpg",
        {
          uploadType: "media",
          destination: "/coverPlaces/" + uuid + ".jpg",
          metadata: {
              metadata: {
                  contentType: "coverImage/jpeg",
                  firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
              }
          }
        },
        (err, coverFile) => {
          if (!err) {
            return response.status(201).json({  // I do NOT get this returned (why not?!)
              coverImageUrl:
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
                bucket.name +
                "/o/" +
                encodeURIComponent(coverFile.name) +
                "?alt=media&token=" +
                uuid,
              coverImagePath: "/coverPlaces/" + uuid + ".jpg"
            });
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            return response.status(500).json({ error: err });
          }
        }
      );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Token is invalid!");
    response.status(403).json({error: "Unauthorized"});
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: The issue is with what the server returns - you're definitely sending both - i.e. the response is controlled by server code which you have not shown

Comment: Ahhh. I suspected as such. That narrows down the problem. So the issue still lies in the server code, which I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826551/uploading-multiple-images-to-firebase-in-react-native. Sorry to trouble you, but do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: your server code doesn't even reference `coverImage` - so I guess that explains everything

Comment: @JaromandaX Woops. Sorry, I sent you the wrong link. This is the actual one aha. Apologies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871349/executing-two-separate-bucket-upload-promises-and-only-getting-in-return-the-s

Comment: @JaromandaX alternatively, say I had two urls to fetch base64 from (image and coverImage). Could I add another fetch to the return in the code above, then parsed the response?